# Algorithm for generating triangle meshes from vertex array

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

Let's say I have a set of points in 3D. The points are uniformly spaced on the x and y axes. So one can think of the points as a function z = f(x,y). As an example, x can be from {0,1,2} and y can be {0,1,2}, giving us a total of nine 3D points on a square grid. I am trying to implement a simple algorithm to generate a triangle mesh of these points, given their  coordinates. I do not know much aboout mesh generation, but I do know that my points are evenly spaced in the x and y dimensions on a grid. So if my points were of the form:
0 0 0
0 5 0
0 0 0

Where the row number represents the y coordinate and the column number represents the x coordinate, and the value represents the z coordinate. This set of points should generate a triangular mesh that looks like a square base pyramid where the peak of the pyramid is at (1,1,5). I am looking for a simple  algorithm that I could code up that would generate such a mesh, given the specifics of this problem.

I have heard of Delaunay triangulation, but am not sure if it is applicable to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution is to consider the four vertices of every mesh and create two triangles, using a diagonal and the four sides.

[image]